# Best open source project hosting site for .NET projects

Tags: c#, .net, open-source

I found a couple questions similar to this, but not specifically for .NET projects, and also both questions I found were pretty old and the answers/votes seemed very out of date since a lot has changed about the sites since the answers were written.

So my question is, what is currently the best hosting site for open source projects using .NET?

Comment: There's a few, launchpad.net, codeplex.com, sourceforge.net...what is it you're looking for exactly?

Comment: I guess which one has the best tools and community for making a .NET based project successful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems highly subjective to me, but I like codeplex.com. It has everything I am looking for :)

Comment: CodePlex is more popular than other sites among Microsoft community.